# Proof of an infinite sum of probabilities

Tags: probability, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative Expected Value Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74186/alternative-expected-value-proof)

If $X$ is a random variable that takes values in the range $\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots \right \}$ how can I prove the following statement?

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X \ge i]$$

I honestly have no idea where to even begin. Even just something to kick off the process would be great.

Comment: Haven't we seen this question or its continuous version about a half-dozen times in the past couple of weeks?

Comment: If that's the case, do you have a link to one of the other half dozen questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\rm\bf Note$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\; \mathrm{P}(X\ge k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\; \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty\; \mathrm{P}(X=\ell)$$
$\rm\bf Rhetorical\text{ } question$: How many times does $\mathrm{P}(X=n)$ appear above for $n=1,2,3,\dots$?

Comment: This is similar to the final proof I found by following [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74186/alternative-expected-value-proof) to [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative/64227#64227) to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formulas_for_special_cases). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following doubly infinite array, where $p_k=P(X=k)$.  We find the sum of **all** the elements of the array in two different ways.

$$\begin{matrix}
p_1 &p_2 & p_3 &p_4 & p_5 &p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
 &p_2 & p_3 &p_4 & p_5&p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
&& p_3 &p_4 & p_ 5&p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
&&&p_4 & p_5 &p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
  &&& & p_5 &p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
  &&&& &p_6 & p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
&&&& && p_7 &p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\ 
&&&& &&&p_8 &p_9&p_{10}&p_{11} &p_{12} &\dots\\
&&&&&&&&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

**The first way:** The first row sum is $P(X \ge 1)$,  the second row sum is $P(X\ge 2)$, the third row sum is $P(X \ge 3)$,  and so on. So the sum of all the  row sums is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\ge k)$.

**The second way:**  The first column sum is $p_1$, the second column sum is $2p_2$, the third column sum is $3p_3$, and so on. So the sum of all the column sums is $p_1+2p_2+3p_3+\cdots$, that is, $E(X)$.