# Finding the expected value of a nonnegative integer valued random variable

Tags: limits, probability-theory, summation, expectation, probability-limit-theorems

If $X$ is a nonnegative integer valued random variable, show that

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X\geq i) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X\geq i).
$$

I'm not sure how to do this. I only know the definition that
$$\mathbb{E}(X):= \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty i \mathbb{P}(X=i)\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geq 0\}} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \mathbb{P}(X=i).
$$

Comment: How many times is $Pr(X=k)$ added into the sum?

Comment: Tip: for positive integer values, $i = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} 1$

Comment: There is a mistake in the statement. The last sum must have $P\{X>i\}$ instead of $P\{X \geq i\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then edit?

Comment: Despite being already closed as a duplicated, this comment is to link this post to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845). Please see the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647)

Answer (score 0):

Assert that most surely $X\in \Bbb N^+$ , then use that for all $k\in\Bbb N^+$, by definition of counting: $k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 1$ .

$$\mathsf E(X) {= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k~\mathsf P(X=k) \\ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathsf P(X=k)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1\\ \vdots \\ = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X>j)}$$

Comment: What if $E[X] = \infty$ ?

Answer (score -1):

If $E[X] < \infty$, then see here:

- [Expectation of an non-negative integer-valued random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457602)
- [Find the Mean for Non-Negative Integer-Valued Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/)

If $E[X] = \infty$, I guess you have to show

$$\lim_{i \to \infty} P(X \ge i) \ne 0 \leftarrow \lim_{i \to \infty} iP(X = i) \ne 0$$