# Expected days to finish a box of cookies

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Adam has a box containing 10 cookies. Each day he eats each cookie with a probability of $\frac12$. Calculate the expected number of days it takes Adam to complete the cookies.

As a start we can set $X$ as the expected days it takes for Adam to finish eating the cookies. However I'm unable to progress further.

Comment: He can eat more than 1

Comment: Let $E[X_i]$ be the expected number of days until all $i$ cookies remaining are eaten.  Can you figure out what $E[X_1]$ is?  Using that knowledge, can you figure out what $E[X_2]$ is?  Using that knowledge, can you figure out what $E[X_3],E[X_4],\dots,E[X_{10}]$ is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E_n$ denote the expected number of days for Adam to finish a box containing $n$ cookies. For a given $n$ and a given $k$ with $0\le k\le n$, with probability $\frac1{2^n}\binom nk$ Adam will eat $k$ cookies on that day and take an expected $E_{n-k}$ more days to finish the box. From here we can derive an equation for $E_n$:
$$\begin{align}
E_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^n}\binom nk(1+E_{n-k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^n}\binom nk(1+E_k)\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^n}\binom nkE_k\\
E_n-\frac1{2^n}E_n&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2^n}\binom nkE_k\\
E_n&=\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2^n}\binom nkE_k\right)
\end{align}$$
The last line is a formula for $E_n$ in terms of all $E_k$ with $0\le k<n$. Trivially we know that $E_0=0$, which allows us to recursively work our way to $E_{10}$. However, beyond the first terms ($E_1=2$, $E_2=\frac83$, etc.) the sequence gets very unwieldy to compute by hand; I wrote [a Python script](https://gist.github.com/Parclytaxel/ee4d59bb9c55e86620d69dc9c8bd3160) for this purpose and got
$$E_{10}=\frac{1777792792}{376207909}=4.725559\dots$$
So Adam will take this many days on average to empty the box.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the cookies are eaten independently, let $X_i$ be the number of days until cookie $i$ is eaten

$X_i \sim Geometric(1/2)$

$P(X_i=k)=(1/2)^k$ for $k\ge 1$

Let $Y=\max(X_1,...,X_{10})$

Then what you want is $E[Y]$

$P(Y\le k)=P(X_1\le k,...,X_{10}\le k)=P(X_1\le k)\cdot...\cdot P(X_{10}\le k)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{10}$

(assuming independence)

$P(Y > k)=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{10}$

Then what you want is:

$E[Y]=\sum_{k>0}P(Y>k)$

Comment: I don't think I get your logic; how do you calculate the actual value of $E[Y]$ from here?

Comment: Last formula is well-known for randoms variables with positive integer values [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable)

Comment: No. I mean a _number_, not an _expression_.

Comment: Still thinking about it, but definitely you can approximate with a couple of terms.

Comment: I don't find a closed form, but a series is still better than nothing. Wolfram Alpha says that it is approximately $3.7256$ (unless i have some mistakes in my derivation)

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk(1-(1-(1%2F2%5Ek))%5E10),+%7Bk,1,Infinity%7D%5D) gives $E[Y]\approx10.46$ according to your derivation. Yes, yes. But this is not correct: Adam eats approximately half the cookies each day on average, and he should be finished within $\sim\log_210$ days.

Comment: Corrected. I had put an extra $k$ in the formula of $E[Y]$. Thanks

Comment: And Mike Spivey's answer here (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41604/what-is-the-expected-maximum-out-of-a-sample-size-n-from-a-geometric-distribut) shows that the answer is $$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \binom{10}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{1}{1-(1/2^i)}={1777792792\over 376207909}.$$

Comment: Yes, that formula is much better than mine! And it seems i still have a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I asked my friend Ruby to eat a couple of jars [that way](https://gist.github.com/ce8a991760d460ea7f81b743feb862e1). She told me $n = 1000000, \text{avg} = 4.724956$ and feels a bit stuffed now.

Comment: I asked her again and got $4.72965$ after she ate another million cookie jars. For more digits I need to wait much longer and risk that she explodes. That would be not nice to her.