# Difficulty understanding "Recursive Method" in Probablity Puzzles App

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation

> You are repeatedly tossing a fair die. How many tosses until you get a 5 or a 6.

I got the answer $3$ using $P_iX_i$ that is creating a infinite series but the hint to the problem says

> One approach is to sum an infinite series. Another is to notice that the problem either ends or restarts after first toss: this lets to express answer recursively, meaning you can set up an equation where answer appears on both sides

I'm not sure how to interpret the second part. It makes sense that the problem end or restarts but I don't understand what to make of it or how to solve it using recursion

Comment: I think they are just referring to the memoryless property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the expected number of rolls is $E$. Then when a roll is made:

- there is a $\frac13$ probability that a 5 or 6 is rolled, stopping the process
- there is a $\frac23$ probability that a 5 or 6 is not rolled, leaving an expected $E$ more rolls to go

This gives the equation
$$E=\frac13\cdot1+\frac23\cdot(1+E)$$
$$\frac13E=1$$
$$E=3$$

Comment: What does $(1+E)$ part mean? Because in the infinite series I made, the second term was $2*2/3*1/3$

Comment: @AnvitGarg $1+E$: one roll has been made, and an expected $E$ more rolls are left since a 5 or 6 was not rolled.

Comment: What is this method called and where can I get some practice questions?

Comment: @AnvitGarg I don't call this a "method", I call this a "hack", which means that its use is situational. For an extravagant example, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000972/357390).

Comment: everything after the first 5 postulates is a hack then  xD