# Probability conditional expected value question

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be the random variable receiving values in $ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Let $Y_i$ be independent, with equal distribution random variables that receive values in the same group.

Let $ Z = \sum_{i=1}^X Y_i$.

Prove that $\mathbb E[Z] = \mathbb E[X]  \mathbb E[Y_1] $

I tried opening the right side, but I've no idea how $Z$ actually works since it always dependent of $X$.

Comment: Hint: $$Z=\sum_{i=1}^\infty Y_i\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant i}$$

Comment: Sorry but I'm still clueless :(

Comment: Hint: write $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z|X]]$

Comment: Bar: Dis you try to take the expectation of both sides of this identity? Ya know, just to see what happens...

Comment: @Bar Vered Didier is saying that if you take the expectation on both sides of the identity, then $E[Y_1]$ can be brought in front of the sum and you are left with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X \ge i)$ which is a [well known fomula for the mean of a non-negative integer-valued random variable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
EZ &=&   E[E[Z|X]] \\
 &=& \sum_n E[Z| X=n]P[X=n] \\
&=&  \sum_n n E[Y_1] P[X=n] \\
&=& \sum_n n  P[X=n] (E[Y_1]) \\
&=& E X E Y_1
\end{eqnarray}
**Addendum**:

@Did suggested that I elaborate one of the steps above:
$E[\sum_{k=1}^X Y_k| X=n] = E[\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k | X=n] = E[\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k] = \sum_{k=1}^n E Y_k = n E Y_1$.
The second equality follows from independence of $Y_k, X$ and the last because
the $Y_k$ are identically distributed.

Comment: First identity is wrong, second identity (is wrong and when corrected) should be proven...

Comment: I had inadvertently omitted a $P[X=n]$ earlier, I had added an elaboration of what I think you were referring to as the second identity...

Comment: This works now.

Comment: Hmm, I can swear that I have not seen this answer when I posted mine. Otherwise I wouldn't have wasted my time to post what is essentially a duplicate of this answer. There is something wrong with this system.

Answer (score 0):

$$E[Z]=\sum_{x=1}^\infty E[Z|X=x]P(X=x)$$

But $Z|X=x$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{x}Y_i$, so $E[Z|X=x]=xE[Y_1]$ (as $Y_i$ are iid). Thus

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty E[Z|X=x]P(X=x)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty xE[Y_1]P(X=x)=E[Y_1]\sum_{x=1}^\infty xP(X=x)=E[Y_1]E[X]$$