# Alternative form of moments of expectation of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a positive discrete random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{N}$ and let $r\geq 1$. Is it true that for the $r$ moment of the expectation the following relation holds:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X^r] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{r-1} \mathbb{P}\{X>k\}.
\end{equation}

I tried using Abel's partial summation formula to show something similar but it did not work out. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: No.  Just test it with $r=1$ or $r=2$ and $P[X=1]=P[X=2]=1/2$. Or easier: Test it with $P[X=1]=1$.

Comment: Even though this post is slightly different, I’d like to link it to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845). Also see the meta post about [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula is not correct (just test it for simple cases as in my comment above).

Assuming that $X \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, I think the formula you want is: 
$$ X^r = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} [(k+1)^r-k^r]1_{\{X>k\}} \implies \boxed{E[X^r] = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} [(k+1)^r-k^r]P[X>k]}$$
where $1_{\{X>k\}}$ is an indicator function that is $1$ if $X>k$, and 0 else.