# The expectation of a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I mostly see stopping times used to stop a random process at time $\tau$. However, in some proofs, the following identity is used, which I cannot deduce myself:

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time. Why
$$
E(\tau) = \sum _{i=1}^\infty P(\tau \geq i).
$$
$\tau$ is a discrete stopping time, so why not
$$
E(\tau) = \sum _{i=1}^\infty iP(\tau = i).
$$

Comment: This is called the tail sum formula, and is true for ANY random variable $\tau$ taking non-negative integer values. Hint: $\tau=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf1(\tau\geq k)$

Comment: This identity is true for all (weakly) positive integer-valued random variables. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable