# Order of Integration E[X]

Tags: probability, integration

I understand that $\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx=E[x]$, and also the logic behind the discrete version [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative). What I don't understand is how the limits of integration change as is seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values), from $(x, \infty)$ to $(0, t)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f_X(t) \,dt \, dx
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^t f_X(t) \, dx \, dt
$$

This transformation is true no matter what the context is (as long as the function is Lebesgue integrable).  Both double integrals are taken over the region where $0 \leq x \leq t$ (which is an angle-like unbounded slice of the plane).  Changing the order of integration usually requires some consideration of how the limits of the region are described in a different way.

The left side has $t \geq x$, where $x$ stays fixed for the integration with respect to $t$.  But on the right side, $t$ stays fixed for the integration with respect to $x$, and we need to state the limits of $x$ in terms of $t$: $x \leq t$.

Comment: that is not true, $f$ must satisfy the assumptions of Fubini's theorem otherwise the other of integration may matter. In particular, if $f_X$ is a prob. density function there is no problem but $f_X$ can not be any arbitrary function.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed, I think.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. So if we had the bounds as x = 5, what would t be?

Comment: $x=5$ does not describe a region of the $x$-$t$ plane with positive area.

Comment: What do you mean?