# Why is the following identity true? $E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P\left \{ Y>x \right \}{d}x$

Tags: probability

For the non-negative r.v. Y, why is the following true:

$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P\left \{ Y>x \right \}{d}x$

Comment: For intuitive explanations, see also the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64186/15941)

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts. The expectation is equal to $\int_0^\infty x dF(x),$ where $F$ is the CDF, which is equal to $1-P(Y>x).$ Integrate by parts, to get your formula.

Comment: Thank you! You answered a different question of mine a couple day ago too, I appreciate it haha.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working on a probability space, let's work on a general measure space $(X,\mu)$ and a nonnegative function $f$.

Define the set \begin{equation}
R(f):=\{(x,y)\in X\times\mathbb{R}: y<f(x)\},
\end{equation} which is `the region below the graph'.

Under reasonable conditions one shows that \begin{equation}
(\mu\times\lambda) (R(f))= \int fd\mu
\end{equation} where $\mu\times\lambda$ is the product measure on $X\times\mathbb{R}$, which says the area of the region below the graph is the integral of the function.

On the other hand, we have the obvious \begin{equation}
(\mu\times\lambda) (R(f))=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_X\chi_{R(f)}d\mu(x) dy=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_X\chi_{\{f(x)>y\}}d\mu(x)dy,
\end{equation} which gives the formula you are looking for once you realize \begin{equation}
\int_X\chi_{\{f(x)>y\}}d\mu(x)=\mu(\{f(x)>y\}).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

i would like to supplement the elegant answers given by Igor and Hui with a more naive approach which i hope will focus attention on the switch in method of summation which is the *technical key* of this result. apologies for any deficiencies as to rigor and clarity of exposition.

suppose we have a discrete random variable $X$ which can take the values $\{x_i\}_{i=1,2,3...}$, where:
$$x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3 \lt \dots
$$
and the probability of the $i^{th}$ value is $p_i$. the expectation is therefore
$$
E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_ip_i
$$
now define the related probabilities $P_i$ where 
$$P_i=P(X \ge x_i)
$$ 
so that 
$$ \begin{aligned}
P_1 & = & p_1+ & p_2+ p_3+p_4... & = 1 \\
P_2 & = &  & p_2+ p_3+p_4... & = 1-p_1
\end{aligned}
$$
and therefore, conversely:
$$
p_1 = P_1-P_2 \\
p_2 = P_2-P_3 \\
\dots
$$
and generally
$$p_n = P_n-P_{n+1}
$$
so that the expectation may also be written as
$$
E(X) = x_1(P_1-P_2)+x_2(P_2-P_3)+x_3(P_3-P_4)+ \dots
$$
which, by a simple regrouping becomes
$$
E(X) = x_1P_1+(x_2-x_1)P_2 + (x_3-x_2)P_3+ \dots
$$
and if we now introduce 
$$
\Delta_{x_1} = x_1 -0 \\
\Delta_{x_2} = x_2-x_1 \\
\Delta_{x_3} = x_3-x_2 \\
$$
and generally
$$\Delta_{x_n}= x_n - x_{n-1}
$$
we can write 
$$
E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P_i\Delta_{x_i}
$$
it should be clear how to pass from this to the integral form of the result desired