# Mean residual life: (improper) integration by parts involving p.d.f

Tags: probability-theory, improper-integrals

Let a random variable $X$ be distributed with p.d.f $f(\cdot)$.

I want to derive the following equality for the mean residual life: 
$$m(x)\equiv\frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}(z-x) f(z)dz}{1-F(x)}=\frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}1-F(z)dz}{1-F(x)}$$

Clearly, I can start by splitting the left-hand-side to get $\frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}z f(z)dz-x\int_{x}^{\infty} f(z)dz}{1-F(x)}=\frac{\left(\int_{x}^{\infty}z f(z)dz\right)-x(1-F(x))}{1-F(x)}$. From this it looks like all I need to do is integration by parts for $\int_{x}^{\infty}z f(z)dz$ with $u(z)=z$ and $v(z)=dF(z)$, but I don't see how this converges to the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $Z-x \equiv h(Z)$. $x$ is treated as fixed here. Then you have

$$m(x)\equiv\frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}(z-x) f(z)dz}{1-F(x)}= \frac {E\Big(h(Z)\cdot \mathbf 1_{\{Z \ge x\}}\Big)}{1-F(x)} \qquad [1]$$

Now the expected value [can be written](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition)
$$E\Big(h(Z)\cdot \mathbf 1_{\{Z \ge x\}}\Big)  = h(x) + \int_{x}^\infty h'(x)P(Z\ge z) dz $$
since $P(h(Z)\ge h(x)) =1$.

But $h(x) = x-x = 0$, $h'(x) = 1$ and $P(Z\ge z) = 1-F(z)$.

So
$$E\Big(h(Z)\cdot \mathbf 1_{\{Z \ge x\}}\Big) = \int_{x}^\infty [1-F(z)] dz$$

which leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The mean residual life $m(x)$ at time $x$ of a system with lifetime $X$,
a nonnegative 
random variable, is the expected lifetime *beyond* $x$ of a system that has 
survived till time $x$, that is, $$m(x) =  E[X\mid X > x] - x.$$  Now,
the *conditional* pdf of $X$ given that $X > x$ is just
$\displaystyle \frac{f(z)}{P\{X > x\}}\mathbf 1_{\{z: z>x\}}
= \frac{f(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathbf 1_{\{z: z>x\}}$ and so 
$$\begin{align}
m(x) &= E[X\mid X > x] -x\\
&= \int_x^{\infty}z\frac{f(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathrm dz - x\\
&= \int_x^{\infty}z\frac{f(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathrm dz - x\int_x^{\infty}\frac{f(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathrm dz\\
&= \int_x^{\infty}\frac{(z-x)f(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathrm dz.
\end{align}$$
The second equality uses the result that for a (integrable)
nonnegative random variable $Y$ with CDF $F_Y(y)$, 
$$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty [1-F_Y(y)]\,\mathrm dy.$$
If you are unfamiliar with this
result, see, for example, 
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64186/15941) for a discussion
of the intuition behind this result and then read the complete proof.
The *conditional CDF* of $X$ given that $X > x$ is given by
$$F_{X\mid X>x}(z\mid X > x) = \frac{F(z)-F(x)}{1-F(x)}\mathbf 1_{\{z: z>x\}}$$
so that the *complementary* CDF has value 
$\displaystyle \mathbf 1_{\{z: 0 < z < x\}} + \frac{1-F(z)}{1-F(x)}
\mathbf 1_{\{z: z>x\}}$ on the
positive real line.  The integral of the complementary CDF over the positive
real line gives
$$E[X \mid X > x] = x + \int_x^\infty \frac{1-F(z)}{1-F(x)}\mathrm dz$$
and since $m(x) =  E[X \mid X > x] - x$, the desired equality follows.