# How to prove the folowing theorem in probablity?

Tags: probability

Show that for any continuous random variable $X$ that takes only positive real
values $\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{Pr}(X\geq x)dx=\mu$ where $\mu$ is the mean.

Comment: This question has been discussed many times on this forum. See, for example, [Intuition behind using complementary CDF to compute expectation for nonnegative random variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative)

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\text{Pr}(X\geq x) dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geq x\}}] dx = \ldots$ What can you say after ?