# Long run percentage of customers who wait for a bus less than x units of time if customers arrive according to a homogenous Poisson process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes, point-processes

Assume that customers arrive to a bus stop according to a homogenous Poisson process with rate $\alpha$ and that the arrival process of buses is an independent renewal process with interarrival distribution $F$. **What is the long run percentage of customers who wait for a bus less than $x$ units of time?**

I tried to solve this problem by considering a renewal reward process. In the case that $x$ is very large so that it imposes no restriction we may proceed as follows to solve a similar problem: we say that a new cycle of length $T$ begins each time a bus arrives. Further, we assume customers pay us money at a rate of $1$ per time unit while they wait for a bus. Then our "reward rate" at any time corresponds to the number of people who are waiting at that time. So, by the renewal reward theorem we have that: average number waiting = $E[R]/E[T]$, where $R$ is the total reward during a cycle. In that case, $E[R] = 1/2E[NT] = 1/2\alpha E[T^2]$, where $N$ is the number of arrival in a cycle, which follows from the definition of a Poisson process and since the points of the Poisson process are uniformly distributed in a cycle conditional on the total number of points in that cycle.

But I don't know how to define the reward with the restriction imposed by $x$. I tried the following conditional expectation: $E[R|T,N]=N x1_{T>x}/2+NT1_{T\leq x}/2$, but got stuck. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Epochs begin/end at each bus arrival, with reward of 1 for each passenger having a short enough wait. $p=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{N(t)}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\frac{R(t)}{t}}{\frac{N(t)}{t}}= \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{t}\cdot \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{N(t)}$ and 
$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{t}=\frac{E[R_1]}{E[T_1]}$.  $E\big[R_1\big]= E\big[E[R_1\vert T_1=t]\big]$ where you split the expectation into $t\in (0,x)$ and $t\gt x$, in each case weighting by $dF(t)$ and using the renewal function amount-- i.e. m(t) for the former and m(x) for the latter. I don't see simplifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing my comment as a full solution.  Main ideas:

**1.)** Poisson process has zero probability of arrival at a particular time -- i.e. there is zero probability of a 'collision'
**2.)** Define a renewal reward process, where a new epoch begins each time a bus arrives, and a reward of 1 for each customer that waited less than $x$ in time.  The long-run probability / percentage of customers with a sufficiently short wait ($\lt x$) is given by
$p=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{N(t)}$
where $N(t)$ of course is the r.v. for the Poisson counting process
**3.)**  The Poisson process is memoryless, which is something we repeatedly exploit, e.g. allows the above renewal reward process to properly work, and the associated renewal function is quite simple $E[N(t)]=m(t)=\frac{t}{\mu}$, and so on.

**The calculations**
$p=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{N(t)}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\frac{R(t)}{t}}{\frac{N(t)}{t}}= \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{t}\cdot \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{N(t)}$
*i.)*  $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{N(t)}=\mu$ by SLLN
*ii.)* $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{t}=\frac{E[R_1]}{E[T_1]}$ where $R_1$ and $T_1$ are rewards and time associated with first epoch.  Using conditioning
$E\big[R_1\big]= E\big[E[R_1\vert T_1=t]\big]$ and in particular
if $t\in(0,x)$ then $E[R_1\vert T_1=t]=m(t)=\frac{t}{\mu}$
if $t\geq x$ then $E[R_1\vert T_1=t]=m(x)=\frac{x}{\mu}$
These both hold by memorylessness. In the latter case this reads: if the epoch length t is at least $x$ long what is the expected number of Poisson arrivals in the interval $(t-x,t)$, but by memorylessness this is the same as the expected number of Poisson arrivals in the interval $(0,x)$ and this is given by $m(x)=\frac{x}{\mu}$.  For the former case it reads, what is the expected number of Poisson arrivals between the beginning and ending of the epoch, i.e. in the interval $(0,t)$ which is given by $m(t)=\frac{t}{\mu}$

Thus
$E\big[R_1\big]= E\big[E[R_1\vert T_1=t]\big]=\big(\int_{0}^x \frac{t}{\mu} dF(t)\big)+ \big(\int_{x}^\infty \frac{x}{\mu} dF(t)\big) = \frac{1}{\mu}\Big(\int_{0}^x t dF(t)\big)+ \big(\int_{x}^\infty x dF(t)\big)\Big)$
$\implies E\big[R_1\big]=\frac{1}{\mu}\cdot E\big[\min(T_1,x)\big]$

putting this all together
$p=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{R(t)}{t}\cdot \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{N(t)}=\Big(\frac{1}{\mu}\cdot E\big[\min(T_1,x)\big]\cdot\frac{1}{E[T_1]}\big)\cdot \big(\mu\big)= \frac{E[\min(T_1,x)]}{E[T_1]}$
$= \frac{\int_0^x Pr(T_1\gt t)dt}{E[T_1]}$

Answer (score 0):

First recall the renewal reward theorem:

$E[R(t)]/t \rightarrow E[R]/E[T]$,

where $E[R]$ is the expected reward during a cycle and $E[T]$ is the expected length of a cycle. We denote $W_i$ the waiting time for customer $i$, $Z_i = 1$ if $W_i < x$, $Z_i = 0$ if $W_i \geq x$ and $N$ denotes the number of customers during a cycle. Then the proportion $\pi$ of customers who waited less than $x$ time units during a cycle with $N$ customers becomes:

$\pi = E[Z_1+...Z_N]/E[N]$.

We have that $E[Z_1+...Z_N|T=t, N=n]=\frac{nx1_{t>x}}{t}+n1_{t \leq x}=n\min(x, t)/t$, considering Poisson points are uniformly distributed conditional on the number of points in the cycle, so that the first equality follows because $x/t$ is the probability that a customer wait less than $x$ time units. Now, because $E[N]=\alpha E[T]$, we have that:

$\pi = E[Z_1+...Z_N]/E[N] = \frac{\alpha E[\min(x, T)]}{\alpha E[T]} = \frac{\int_0^xP(T>t)dt}{E[T]}$.

The rationale for the last equality is explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259819/expected-value-of-the-minimum-of-a-non-negative-random-variable-and-a-constant) post.