# Probability function of $Y=max\{X,m\}$ for $m$ positive integer when $X$ is geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

$X$ has geometric distribution so $f_X(x)=p(1-p)^x$.
I wrote this:
$$f_Y(y)=P(Y=y)=P(max\{X,m\}=y)$$
So if $y=m$ it means that $X<m$ so $f_Y(y)=P(X<m)=1-P(X\ge m)=1-(1-p)^m$
and if $y = m+1,m+2,...$ then $f_Y(y)=p(1-p)^y$

Is it right?

Comment: Almost — $y=m \implies x \leq m$

Comment: No. $((max\{X,m\}=m)$ occurs if and only if $(X\leq m)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected value of the minimum of a non-negative random variable and a constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259819/expected-value-of-the-minimum-of-a-non-negative-random-variable-and-a-constant)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming as correct your $f_X(x)$, that is $X$ is a geometric rv counting the failures before the first success, your pmf $f_Y(y)$ does not sum up to 1...

Observe that $Y=m$ when $X\le m$ and this happens with probability $1-(1-p)^{m+1}$ thus

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y] =
\begin{cases}
1-(1-p)^{m+1},  & \text{if $y=m$ } \\
p(1-p)^y, & \text{if $y=m+1,m+2,m+3,\dots$ }\\
0, & \text{elsewhere }
\end{cases}$$

---

As you can see, this pmf works, being

$$1-(1-p)^{m+1}+p\sum_{y=m+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^y=1-(1-p)^{m+1}+p\frac{(1-p)^{m+1}}{1-(1-p)}=1$$