# Independent random variables and integrability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

[image]

This is a problem that I am stuck at. I think I have to prove the hint first. But I can't find a way to prove the 'only if' part of the hint. (the 'if' part is just manifest). Could anyone help me how to prove the hint?

Also, I can't think of a way to prove that if $\frac{X_n}{n}$ goes to $0$ P-a.s, then $X_1$ is integrable when independence is assumed. I think I have to use some Kolmogorov's law of large numbers..but just stuck now. Please could anyone help me with this also?

Comment: What does $n|\varepsilon$ mean?  Is it just supposed to be multiplication $n\varepsilon$?  It looks like a printing error.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I changed the pictrue. Yes, it is multiplication.

Comment: Why does the step you say is "just manifest" seem manifest to you?

Comment: This looks like a Borel-Cantelli type of problem (rather than Kolmogorov LLN).  To prove the hint, you might use the fact that if $Y$ is a non-negative random variable, then $E[Y] = \int_0^{\infty} Pr[Y>y]dy$, and relate that integral to a sum.

Comment: Why does the equality hold? Could you prove it in more detail?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, for proving "if (X_n)/n  goes to 0  P-a.s, then X 1 is integrable" could you give me some advice?

Comment: Have you looked at Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: I am looking at it now, trying to figure out how to apply this lemma to the problem. But can't find a way yet.

Comment: I think I found a way out. Thank you for your help,