# Combining probability distributions for identical processes.

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a computer that solves a certain problem in an average time T. The average time T is calculated from the probability distribution p(t), where p(t) is the probability that the program halts at time t meaning the problem has been solved.

Now suppose we run n identical computers simultaneously and independent of each other solving the same problem as I just described. I am interested in the new average time that it takes before atleast one of the computers have solved the problem.

I'm not sure how I should tackle this problem.

Comment: Do you know anything about $p(t)$?

Comment: No, p(t) can be anything in general.

Comment: Then use Nick Peterson's answer and independence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ be the random times it takes each computer to solve the problem.  What you're interested in here is the random variable
$$
T_{\min}:=\min\{T_1,\ldots,T_n\}.
$$

Given that, here's my hint:
$$
P(T_{\min}>t)=P(T_1>t,T_2>t,\ldots,T_n>t).
$$

Comment: Don't understand.

Comment: That's an incredibly unhelpful comment.  Do you not understand what I said?  Do you not understand how it leads toward a solution? Please be more specific.

Comment: How do I calculate the new average time if I know P(T_min > t) ? I assume P(T_min > t) refers to the probability that it takes more then t time before atleast one computer gives the answer. BUt where do I go from there?

Comment: @Higgsino $$E(T_{\mathrm{min}})=\int_0^\infty P(T_{\mathrm{min}}>t)\,dt$$

Comment: But now T_min refers to an interval. When I caclulate an average I usually take p(t) at a specifik time and then multiply with the time and integrate to get the average. I just don't understand how your integral will give the average of T_min.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative