# Expectation as product measure

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, product-space

I am reading a result that for a nonnegative random variable $X$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$,

$EX = (P \times  \lambda)\{(\omega,x): 0 \leq x \leq X(\omega)\}$,

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

What is the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 0):

well, suppose $\Omega$ consists of finitely many elements, $X$ some random variable. you have $$EX= X(\omega_1)P(\omega_1) + ... +X(\omega_n)P(\omega_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n(P(\omega_i)\int_0^{X(\omega_i)}d\lambda) = (X\times\lambda)\{(x,\omega): x<X(\omega)\}$$

This answer might be helpful:
[Intuition behind using complementary CDF to compute expectation for nonnegative random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative)