# Where does this equality come?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

I need to prove this theorem :

Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $|E(X)|<\infty $ if and only if

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|>n)<\infty$$

I understand the proof until somewhere but I have problem understanding where does the following equality come i.e.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(n-1<|X|\leq n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X|>n)$$

Can someone help me understand why this equality holds.

Comment: What is the sample space of the random variable? $\mathbb N$?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative

Answer (score 1):

Noting that, assuming $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is defined, $|\mathbb{E}(X)|<\infty$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$ suppose $X \geq 0$.
Define $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ the probability space and suppose $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable, i.e. is measurable and not necessarly discrete.

An easy consequence of Fubini-Tonelli's theorems is that:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int X d\mathbb{P}=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>t)dt$$

Thus, if in your case $X(\Omega)=\mathbb{N}$, the last integral simply became the summation you need.

In addition, if $X(\Omega)=\mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(n-1<X\leq n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>n)$$
holds for the same reasonement.

In fact if $A_n=\{\omega \in \Omega: n-1<X(\omega) \leq n \}$, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int X d\mathbb{P}=\sum_n \int_{A_n}X d\mathbb{P}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(n-1<X\leq n)$$

because $X$ is equal to $n$ in $A_n$ because $X(\Omega)=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What if $X$ is not discrete? It seems more reasonable to assume that $X$ is not necessarily so, since the second equality in the OP is more complicated than necessary if $X$ were discrete.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist The statement holds, mutatis mutandis, also if $X$ is not discrete. I tried to edit my answer.

Comment: I agree, but given the OP doesn’t see how to establish the equality in their question, I find it hard to see how they would see how to do so from your answer without looking up the use of Tonelli’s theorem that you reference.