# Expectation of X^2 using complement of CDF

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, improper-integrals, expected-value

For a [nonnegative random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative)
$$E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X >x)dx$$

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcGaICSCsc4) on a question from IIT JAM 2023 extends it to
$$E[X^2]=\int_0^\infty 2x P(X >x)dx$$

How was the result was arrived at?
Where can I get references for such results? Books or structured references (rather than single links preferred).

Comment: $P(X^{2}>x)=P(X>\sqrt x)$ if $X$ is non-negative. Apply your first formula and make the change of variable $y=\sqrt x$

Comment: @geetha290krm I did what you said. Are the steps correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$E[X^2]=\int_0^\infty P(X^2 >x)dx=\int_0^\infty P(X>\sqrt{x})dx$$

Substitute $t=\sqrt{x}\implies t^2 =x\implies 2t\text{ } dt=dx$
$$=\int_0^\infty P(X>t) \text{ } 2t \text{ }dt$$

And since the variable of integration is a dummy variable, change back to $x$:
$$=\int_0^\infty 2x P(X >x)dx$$